# Elección incorrecta en la medalla de la encuesta de Stack Overflow

Tags: discusión, soporte, medallas

Hice la encuesta anual de Stack Overflow y sin querer elegí mi medalla para Stack Overflow y querría saber si existe la posibilidad de cambiarla a Stack Overflow en Español.

Comment: la encuesta solamente se encuentra en SO en ingles, por lo que no creo que la puedas conseguir de momento....

Comment: @JavierG.Raya Al final de la encuesta te permite elegir en donde recibirla, pero me confundí :(

Comment: a pues eso no lo sabia

Comment: @JavierG.Raya de hecho, la medalla esta tambien en SO en Español, miralo en [medalla censo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/129/census)

Comment: Y como se realiza la encuesta xD

Comment: @JavierG.Raya metete en [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) y sale ahi mismo

Comment: para mi lo raro es que escogí que quería que saliera en SOes y no me sale ... XD

Comment: ha me demoro 10 minutos en aparecer XD

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 si, tarda un ratillo en aparecer